# How to sync Outlook contacts with GMail and Windows Mobile?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, windows-mobile, contacts

What's the best way to keep my contacts in sync between Outlook (Exchange), my free GMail account, and my Windows Mobile phone?  Ideally I'd like to be able to make a change in any of these places and have it sync to the others.  If that's not possible my preference would be to do all editing in Outlook.

**Update:**
Sorry, forgot to mention that I can't use Google's ActiveSync option with the phone because I need to sync mail & calendar with my office's Exchange server.  I'm just looking for a way to keep *contacts* in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Soocial](http://www.soocial.com) to sync Outlook and Google Mail Contacts with good results. Since your phone syncs to your Outlook/Exchange contacts, it gets updated as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should have all you need from the Google to Windows Mobile side
http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138636

Answer (score 2):

Google now offers all the functionality that you're looking for:

[You can setup WM to sync directly to google.](http://www.google.com/mobile/products/sync.html#p=default) (use this all the time)

[And a similar system for syncing directly to Outlook](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/outlook_sync.html#utm_medium=et&utm_source=us-en-entblog&utm_campaign=en) (haven't used this)

Comment: Isn't Google Apps sync (your second link) only for Google Apps customers?  I'm only running a free GMail account.

Comment: Looks like it is.  I'm not used to Google Apps users getting extrea features, normally we get the short end of the stick :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a registry setting that you can change to allow it to sync with multiple Exchange accounts. When my ATT Tilt (HTC something or other) was running WinMo 6 it worked like a charm. When I updated using HTC's 6.1 ROM, I've had odd issues...

[Here's where I found the information.](http://www.bitshift.ch/eng/support/kbase/000003.asp) (I think... doesn't seem to want to come up here at work today)